# Как задействовать другой класс при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: java, логика

Есть классы
Class_1
Class_2
Class_3
Class_4

Как сделать так чтобы при нажатии на кнопку в интерфейсе который создаётся в классе 1 был задействован метод в классе 2 который отвечает за изменение изображения в интерфейсе (который был создан в классе 1) после чего появляется 2 кнопка (в этом же интерфейсе) которая создаётся с вызовом метода который отвечает за смену картинки на заднем фоне которая отвечает за смену картинки которая есть в 3 классе и также с 4 классом

Т.е
Нажал на  button_1 в классе 1 - задействован метод в 2 классе который меняет картинку и создаёт кнопку button_2
Нажал на button_2 - поменялась картинка которая прописана в 3 классе и появился button_3 который отвечает также за смену картинки и создание кнопки button_4

помогите пожалуйста постарался максимально подробно описать будут вопросы - буду дополнять вопрос

Comment: Можете менее абстрактно описать? Может что-то уже есть готовое. Например как метод в классе 2 создает кнопку в интерфейсе.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понимаю что вы хотите сделать, то вам необходимо передавать между класами вопервых JFrame - так называемая рамка для окна. Можете создать его в первом класе а потом в момент создания других класов передавать им даный объект. Далее необходимо обработать события кнопок и вызывать методы с ваших класов.

Таким образом второй клас будет слушателем события кнопки из первого класа и так далее. Так же необходимо в момент создания и добавления новой кнопки на JFrame добавлять слушателей из следующих класов и так до последего четвертого класа.

Имея объект JFrame во всех класах вы сможете без особого труда обрабатывая события нажатия кнопки из определенного класа вызывать метод из другого класа который в свою очередь будет добавлять новую кнопку на JFrame общий для всех класов.

А на счет Image сделайте тоже самое что из JFrame только не нужно вам новых изображений по нажатию на соответствующию кнопку можно просто меня путь для изображения. За более конкретными моментами, типа что такое JFrame почитайте про javax.swing - создание GUI